# How to Call a Function when Ok is pressed in an UIAlert

Tags: swift, uialertview

Im try to simply call a function called "GoToNewShoot" When the user press the "ok" button when the Alert pops up Thanks!.

Code:

```
   @IBAction func GobacktoCamera(sender: AnyObject) {
    var alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Just Checking", message: "Are You Sure You Want to Start over ", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can do it by using handler from `addAction` this way:

```
@IBAction func GobacktoCamera(sender: AnyObject) {

    var alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Just Checking", message: "Are You Sure You Want to Start over", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default, handler: { action in
        //run your function here
        self.GoToNewShoot()
    }))

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


func GoToNewShoot(){

    println("Method Called")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alerty.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Just Checking",
                      style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
                    handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in print("Are You Sure You Want to Start over")}))
```